# jQuery: Hover-Over Animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

First of all, my jQuery (or Javascript period) isn't good.

I am trying to make an image roll-over to a new image when I hover over it using the jQuery animate function.

Here is what I have working (image rolls over to text): http://jsfiddle.net/Draven/NJCUn/5/

Here's what I was hoping would work (replaced text with an image): http://jsfiddle.net/Draven/U7m25/4/

I believe the problem is because the script is looking for all the `img` tags in the `<li>`. Is there a way I can make it pick the first `img` tag?

Comment: [jQuery :first selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).  But might be better off giving your items explicit IDs and referencing via #id selectors.

Comment: I assume I am using it correctly, but it doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/Draven/yDtkZ/8/

Comment: Nope, you'd want to apply it to your img tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

working example:

```
$('ul.hover_block li').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('img').eq(1).animate({
        top: '425px'
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 500
    });
}, function() {
    $(this).find('img').eq(1).animate({
        top: '0px'
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 500
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yDtkZ/20/

Comment: Very nice. But the images are opposite. Why is that?

Comment: Just reverse the order of the images in the HTML and it works fine. The second image is going right on top of the first one, since they're both positioned absolute.

Comment: Yeah, I knew to switch the `img` order. I was just wondering why it would do that. Thank you!